# How to find the arc length between any two points (real numbers) on the circumference of a circle with center at the origin?

Tags: geometry, circles, graphing-functions, arc-length

Suppose I'm given two points: **(x1, y1)** and **(x2, y2)** (which are real numbers) lying on the circumference of a circle with radius **r** and **centred at the origin**, how do I find the arc length between those two points (the arc with shorter length)?

Comment: Usually it's good practice to show the steps of what you did to try to solve the problem yourself. You can edit a question to add such details. It's also preferred to use MathJax to format your formulas to be easier to read: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: But even without the effort you have already gotten two answers. They disagree with each other; can you tell which of them (if either) is correct?

Comment: By the way, there are at least five different methods that can be relatively obvious depending on what you know about coordinate geometry, trigonometry, and vectors. Part of the reason for asking for your attempt is because in some questions it helps people figure out what kind of answer would actually be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, they don't give same answers. The one with finding angle and then finding arc is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the following situation:

[image]

Points $A$ and $B$ are given by their coordinates. So you can calculate their distance. Now, we have an isosceles triangle with given side lengths. We can calculate $\alpha$.

Given $\alpha$ and $r$, the arclength can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Find the distance $d$ between these two points. Your desired arc $\alpha$ is obtained from solving $\frac{\pi}{\alpha} = \frac{D}{d}$, where $D = 2r$ is the diameter of the circle

Comment: Do you see where you made a mistake?